# How do I prevent the user moving to a new record with dirty data?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

If I'm creating a new record, and have logic that fires when the user presses the save button. This creates a problem that the user can create a new record, but not press the 'save' button, but just navigate to a new/previous record. The data will be saved, but the other VBA logic won't be fired.

I wish to prevent this, so which would be the best way? I would like navigation to be allowed on the form, just not when the record is new and dirty (navigation during updates are fine).

I've thought of two ideas, but am not sure how to implement either, nor which would be more logical. How would I do these:

**Idea 1**: Disable the navigation when a record is new and is dirty

**Idea 2**: Fire the 'presave' logic when the user navigates away from a dirty new record.

Comment: Why not run code in the before update event?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your 'logic' in the Form Event "After update"

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    'do some logic stuff here or call another method
End Sub
```

When I tried it, Access was able to distinguish correctly if the form is dirty or not before firing this event. But you should try it on your own.